# Do milk crates have registered owners?

Tags: criminal-law, property, trespass, conversion, fda

Is there an actual milk crate registration system? What is the law by which use by other than the registered owner is punishable?

Is there an index I can use to see who these milk crates are registered to?

Where can I register my milk crates to reserve my rights?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't want to, but I have to... do milk crates have cereal numbers?

Comment: And what's the penalty for using an *unregistered* milk crate in public?

Comment: Color me educated! http://modernfarmer.com/2013/08/illegal-use-milk-crates-anything-besides-milk/

Comment: I suspect that the registration is effected by printing an ownership notice on the crate itself.

Comment: British beer kegs certainly do... http://www.kegwatch.co.uk/

Answer (score 4):

Here is the state of California code regarding the question. I am sure a state by state inquiry could reveal other statutes.

http://www.leginfo.ca.gov/cgi-bin/displaycode?section=pen&group=00001-01000&file=565-566

In California there is no specific registry but registration is performed by marking the container with a registered brand.